# Julia studio write() error

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I am getting the weirdest error in using the `write()`function:

```
julia> write(0.1)
�8

julia> 
������?
```

These are just the commands I'm writing in the console, as you can see. What could be going wrong?

Note: I'm using `Julia Studio 0.4.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/stdlib/base/#i-o):

> `write(stream, x)`: Write the canonical **binary** representation of a value to the given stream.

I suspect that you want to use `print` rather than `write`.

Comment: Should I use `print()` instead?